# How to know the partition?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 11.10).
Well, when I call the system call open, for example in a C program:

```
size_t filedesc = open("testfile.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0640);
```

How can I access the partition, I mean is there a way to return the partition used?

The system call open is the defined above:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, int, mode)
```

If I want, I can put a `printk("%s",filename)` and see the path. But how I can access the partition?

An example: I have two archives example.txt in two different partitions (for example /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2).

Then I call the system call open: Lets suppose I called the example.txt in the partition /dev/sda2.
Is there a way to acess the partition (for example, `printk(KERN_ALERT "%s",partition)`) using the open system call?

Comment: I don't understand if you speak of user-land or kernel-land. I'm guessing it is user-land (as seen from an application), but then why bother about `printk` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do all this stuff? Your explanations are confusing!

Comment: @Basile is right, I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish. I think we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here -- you're asking how to implement a solution for a problem, but if we knew the problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to come up with much better suggestions. So: What problem are you **really** trying to solve? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing as simple as you might hope.

Within the `do_sys_open()` function, immediately before `return fd;`, the `struct file *f` points to a legitimate, opened, `struct file`.

The `struct file` contains a `struct path f_path`.

The `struct path` contains a `struct vfsmount *mnt`. `struct vfsmount` represents every mounted filesystem on the system.

The `struct vfsmount` contains a `struct super_block *mnt_sb`.

The `struct super_block` contains a `struct block_device *s_bdev`.

The `struct block_device` contains a `struct hd_struct *bd_part`.

The `struct hd_struct` contains a `struct device __dev` and an `int partno`. Together, these two define which partition your file is located on.

**Update**

I had originally stopped looking when I found the device and partition number references, since I assumed that was all that was required to put together the human-friendly string. But when looking again with fresh eyes, I see there is more:

The `struct hd_struct` contains a `struct partition_meta_info *info`.

The `struct partition_meta_info` contains a field:

```
    u8 volname[PARTITION_META_INFO_VOLNAMELTH];
```

This field is name of the device you're after.

Comment: The above is probably as seen from inside the kernel. From inside an application, only syscalls are involved.

Comment: The question _is_ tagged [tag:kernel].

Comment: The kernel does not have an `open` function, it provides it as a system call to applications.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for the questioner to respond to your comment. :) He _did_ say he `printk("%s",filename)` to see the path...

Comment: Perhaps the original poster don't understand well the kernel-land <> user-land difference (at least this is what I inferred when he mention both `open` and `printk`).

Comment: If he's programming in the kernel, he better learn quick :) it isn't very forgiving when you screw up.

Comment: Well ,I found all the structures you posted here . What I am trying to do , for example , I want to put a printk(KERN_ALERT "%s",partition) inside the open system call or in the do_sys_open() and prints the partition of the  file that I opened now.I am calling the system call open in a program.But I am programming in kernel level.I think my problem is related with the first answer.(The struct device__dev and int partno)

Comment: Bas ically , I am trying to do this. I write a programa in C.This program will have a system call open , defined like this : open("test.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0640).So I will call the system call open aend I want to print the partition of the archive s"test.txt", and to print I want put a printk() inside the system call open() or do_sys_open().My problem is how to find the partition and print it. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Are you working in kernel land or in user land? Applications (i.e. user-land programs) are doing syscalls like open, stat... printk can only happen inside the kernel, and the kernel does not have open (it provides such a syscall).

Comment: Ok.My program is in user level , I create my program in user level and I call open in the user level.So,as open is a system call , the system enters in kernel level and executes the open.But I want to change my system call open(kernel level) and I want to put  a printk to print the partition of the path that I opened now.I mean , the kernel level will print the partition when I call the open system call.I will call the open system call in user level , but will print in the kernel level.If it still confusing,let me know.Thank you.

Comment: An example:I will call this in user level ,open("test.txt",O_CREAT |O_WRONLY,0640).                                                                                                                        But I will print in kernel level,I will put a printk in the system call or in a function inside the kernel level and this printk will print the partition of the archive("teste.txt").

Comment: @UserJ The kernel has many different layers, the system calls or the file system doesn't know or care about partitions, that's usually handle by the block layer(and in some cases, a file system can be spread over many partitions and drives). You'll have to go through a few hoops to resolve the partition. Take a look at statvfs() and cross reference that with the mount points.

Comment: @sarnold  Basically I did what you told me , then inside the device ,I printk the "init_name" ,but the result was **null** . Do you know exactly the name of the variable that contains the name of the partition of the file?Because I'm having problem finding this.For example I openned a file ,and I want to print on the screen something like this : "dev/sda".Thank you for your answer and this helped me a lot ,but I still don't know how to find the variable that constains the name of the partition .

Answer (score 2):

Thru a shell, `df /some/dir` gives you the file-system involved. Programmatically, with [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call, you get the `st_dev` field.

(**added:**) I don't guess what you want to do exactly, but perhaps doing that using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) could be simpler.